# R - Combine names with duplicate dates into single row

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
           date = c("2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-9", "2018-11"))
```

and I want to combine any of the names that share a date with another into a single row separated by a comma with the second column showing the date they share

```
data.frame(name = c("a,c", "b", "d"),
           date = c("2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11"))
```

Comment: @RichScriven Provided it's not a typo in the sample data, this is not quite a dupe, since OP needs to take care of different date formats prior to aggregating (e.g. `"2018-09"` vs. `"2018-9"`).

Answer (score 1):

**I assume the different date formats from your sample data are real, i.e. you have data where `"2018-09"` and `"2018-9"` correspond to the same month+year.**

In that case you can do the following

```
df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(date, "-01"), "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(name = toString(name)) %>%
    mutate(date = format(date, format = "%Y-%m"))
#    # A tibble: 3 x 2
#  date    name
#  <chr>   <chr>
#1 2018-09 a, c
#2 2018-10 b
#3 2018-11 d
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
       date = c("2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-9", "2018-11"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `dplyr` with `group_by` and `summarize`.

Since you're working with dates, it's important that you get them into a standardized format (which they aren't in your example) so that identical dates are considered identical.

The `lubridate` package is, in my opinion, the easiest way to do this. In the below example, we parse the date variable as a 4-digit year `Y` and decimal month `m`, then group by identical dates as before:

```
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
           date = c("2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-9", "2018-11"))
df2 %>%
    mutate(date = lubridate::parse_date_time(date, 'Ym')) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(name = paste0(name, collapse = ','))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  date                name 
  <dttm>              <chr>
1 2018-09-01 00:00:00 a,c  
2 2018-10-01 00:00:00 b    
3 2018-11-01 00:00:00 d
```

Answer (score 0):

Using R base `aggregate` and `df` from @divibisan answer:

```
> aggregate(name~date, data=df,  paste, collapse = ",")
     date name
1 2018-09  a,c
2 2018-10    b
3 2018-11    d
```